# Passing a SQL parameter to an IN() clause using typed datasets in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, parameter-passing, strongly-typed-dataset

First apologies as there are similar questions on this site, but none of them answer this problem directly.

Im using typed datasets in VS 2010. I create a TableAdapter in a Dataset with a query like:

```
SELECT * from Table WHERE ID IN(@IDs)
```

Now if I call: `TableAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable,"1,2,3")` an error occurs stating that VS cannot convert 1,2,3 to type int. Fair enough.

So then i decide to change the Parameter (i.e. @IDs) type to string in the Parameter collection. Try again - still the same error message.

So is there any way this typed dataset can accept my "1,2,3" parameter? At the moment i only have a few parameters to pass, so i could easily just create 5 or so parameters and pass them separately, but what if there are hundreds? Is there any way I can call the `Fill()` method with my comma separated parameter?

(i know i can use Dynamic SQL to create the statement and execute it but would prefer if there is another way allowing me to keep my typed dataset for use in e.g. ReportViewer/bindingsources)

Comment: Is it SQL Server? If yes, which version?

Comment: SQL server 2008 (and higher) allows table-valued parameters. But this requires a TYPE definition on the SQL server. If  you are allowed to use create a TYPE on your server, I can answer the question.

Comment: Yes i have full access, please elaborate.

Comment: For anyone reading this, please take a look at the answers by Joe and Simon M. Both helped my problem

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570393/postgres-integer-arrays-as-parameters/7733714#7733714

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use a single parameter for a list of values in this way.  But there may be database-specific ways to achieve what you want.  For example, with SQL Server 2005 or later you could create a table-valued function to split your string parameter, something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_Split
(
@InputString VARCHAR(MAX)
,@Separator VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @ValueTable TABLE (Value VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SeparatorIndex INT, @TotalLength INT, @StartIndex INT, @Value VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @TotalLength=LEN(@InputString)
    SET @StartIndex = 1

    IF @Separator IS NULL RETURN

    WHILE @StartIndex <= @TotalLength
    BEGIN
        SET @SeparatorIndex = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @InputString, @StartIndex)
        IF @SeparatorIndex > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @StartIndex, @SeparatorIndex-@StartIndex)
            SET @StartIndex = @SeparatorIndex + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            Set @Value = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @StartIndex, @TotalLength-@StartIndex+1)
            SET @StartIndex = @TotalLength+1
        END
        INSERT INTO @ValueTable
        (Value)
        VALUES
        (@Value)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

You would then use it as follows:

```
SELECT * from Table WHERE ID IN (SELECT CAST(Value AS INT) FROM F_Split(@IDs, ','))
```

Comment: Works great. I just want to add one thing to make clear. @IDs has to be like "1,2,3" in the query. I was confused when I tried it.

Comment: but how do you declare the function in the typed dataset?

Answer (score 9):

I tried a workaround for using string "contains" concept in SQL way:

In your case, change the SQL -

Original:

> SELECT * from Table WHERE ID IN(@IDs)

***Become:***

> SELECT * from Table WHERE **CharIndex(','+Cast(ID As Varchar(10))+',',@IDs) > 0**

With .net code -

Original:

> TableAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable,"1,2,3")

***Become:***

> TableAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable,"**,1,2,3,**")

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect.

Comment: Works Perfect! It even changed the paramter type accordingly

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2008 has a feature called [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

So you need to

1. define your query as `SELECT * from Table WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM (@IDs))`
2. go back in the TableAdapter visual designer in Visual Studio, and update the @IDS parameter to modify the @IDS parameter as DbType=Object and ProviderType=Structured
3. run this SQL batch in the database your are using: `CREATE TYPE MyIntArray AS TABLE ( Value INT );GO`. 
   This will create a MyIntArray "table type" with just one column of INT type.
4. Now the tricky thing is to pass the "MyIntArray" type to the TableAdapter, on the ADO.NET side.

Unfortunately the Table Adapter designer does not support the `SqlParameter.TypeName` argument, so we need to fix it by ourselves. The goal is to modify the `CommandCollection` property of the generated TableAdapter class. Unfortunately, this property is protected, so you have to derive the TableAdapter or for example use Reflection to tweak it. Here is an example with a derived class:

```
    public class MyTableAdapter2 : MyTableAdapter
    {
        public MyTableAdapter2()
        {
            SqlCommand[] cmds = base.CommandCollection;
            // here, the IDS parameter is index 0 of command 1
            // you'll have to be more clever, but you get the idea
            cmds[1].Parameters[0].TypeName = "MyIntArray";
        }
    }
```

And this is how you can call this method:

```
        MyTableAdapter t = new MyTableAdapter2();

        // create the TVP parameter, with one column. the name is irrelevant.
        DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
        tvp.Columns.Add();

        // add one row for each value
        DataRow row = tvp.NewRow();
        row[0] = 1;
        tvp.Rows.Add(row);

        row = tvp.NewRow();
        row[0] = 2;
        tvp.Rows.Add(row);

        row = tvp.NewRow();
        row[0] = 3;
        tvp.Rows.Add(row);

        t.Fill(new MyDataTable(), tvp);
```

Comment: This was the only simple 1 TVP row example I could find with TableAdapters. Works great! Thanks!

Comment: You will also need to add execute permissions for the type "GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE ::MyIntArray to user;
GO"

Comment: quite possibly the enclosing brackets around IDs are superfluous

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by setting the `ClearBeforeFill` property to to `false` and filling the `TableAdapter` in  a `foreach` loop.

```
List<string> aList = new List<string>();
aList.Add("1");
aList.Add("2");
aList.Add("3");

yourTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
yourTableAdapter.Fill(yourDataSet.yourTableName, ""); //clears table

foreach (string a in aList)
{
    yourTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;
    yourTableAdapter.Fill(yourDataSet.yourTableName, a);
}
yourTableAdapter.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only database I know of that can use parameters from .NET in an `IN` clause is PostgreSQL, because PostgreSQL has a concept of arrays that can be used with `IN` and Npgsql allows array (or `IEnumerable<T>`) parameters.

With other databases you have to either construct the SQL, or pass a string to a database procedure that converts it to the 0-or-more parameters and then acts on them.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe is right.

Or you can use foreach loop to do that.

Something like:

```
   int[] arr = new int[3]; 
    arr[0] = "1";        
    arr[1] = "2";             
    arr[2] = "3";             

foreach(vat data in arr)
{

//Do your Code here

// 
var MyDatatable = obj.GetDatabyID(data);

TableAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable);

}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You also can create a list of IDs parameters
so instead of using @IDs you will use @ID1, @ID2, @ID3, etc

```
var sql = "SELECT * from Table WHERE ID IN (" + getKeys(values.Count) + ")";
```

And getKeys(count) do something like this:

```
var result = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                result += ", @ID" + i;
            }
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? string.Empty : result.Substring(1);
```

and Finally, add the parameters:

```
foreach (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID" + i, SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = values[i]});
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **XML** to pass in a parameter list into a stored procedure:

1) In Visual Studio:

Create a new Tableadapter and create a Typed Dataset to get a single record:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (ID = @ID)
```

2) In SQL Server Manager:

Create a stored procedure with the same select fields as your typed dataset:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrsp_GetIds]
    @paramList xml = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

/*
Create a temp table to hold paramaters list.
Parse XML string and insert each value into table.
Param list contains: List of ID's
*/
DECLARE @tblParams AS TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @tblParams(ID) 
    SELECT 
        XmlValues.ID.value('.', 'INT')
    FROM 
        @paramList.nodes('/params/value') AS XmlValues(ID)

/* 
Select records that match ID's in param list:
*/
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE 
    ID IN (
        SELECT ID FROM @tblParams
    )
```

3) In Visual Studio:

Add a New Query to your Tableadapter, select the stored procedure created above **usrsp_GetIds** and name it **FillBy_Ids**. This creates the command:

```
TableAdapter.FillBy_Ids(@paramList)
```

4) In Visual Studio:

In your .net code create a utility function to convert an array of strings to XML:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Converts an array of strings to XML values.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>Used to pass parameter values to the data store.</remarks>
    Public Shared Function ConvertToXML(xmlRootName As String, values() As String) As String
        'Note: XML values must be HTML encoded.
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.AppendFormat("<{0}>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlRootName))
        For Each value As String In values
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.Append(vbTab)
            sb.AppendFormat("<value>{0}</value>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value))
        Next
        sb.AppendLine()
        sb.AppendFormat("</{0}>", xmlRootName)
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
```

**Usage Example:**

Fill your data table using the strongly typed functions by passing a list of strings as a parameter:

```
'Create a list of record IDs to retrieve:
Dim ids as New List(of String)
ids.Add(1)
ids.Add(2)
ids.Add(3)

'Convert the list of IDs to an XML string:
Dim paramsXml As String = ConvertToXML("params", ids.ToArray)

'Get the records using standard DataTable & TableAdapter methods:
Using myDT As New MyDataTable
    Using myTA As New MyTableAdapter

        myTA.FillBy_Ids(myDT, paramsXml)

        For Each row In myDT
            'do stuff:
        Next

    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

YOUHOUHHH it works !!!

As the different elements searched are fixed length order numbers with a predefined header ("2021"), I even did not put a separator.

MySQL :

```
[...] WHERE
    (INSTR(@orders, CAST(orders.numorder AS CHAR (11))) > 0)
[...]
```

C# :

```
 string allOrders="";
    foreach (string orderNum in ordersNum)
    {
         allOrders += orderNum;
         textBoxOrdersNum.AppendText ( orderNum+"\r\n");
    }
tousDetailsNomenclatureParOrderTableAdapter.FillTousDetailsNomenclatureParOrder(conduiteDataSet.TousDetailsNomenclatureParOrder, allOrders);
```