# How to create SQL Query with like item1, item2, item3 format at Delphi?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using `CheckListEdit` component at Delphi which enables to select more than one item at time. When extracted using CheckListEdit1.Text, I get selected items in the String format like `[item1, item2, item3]` which I trimmed further to discard first and last character to get final string as 'item1, item2, item3'.

My code is as follows

```
glist := CheckListEdit1.Text;
glistindex := Length(glist);
Delete(glist,glistindex,1);
Delete(glist,1,1);
```

//Here I am getting glist = 'item1, item2, item3..' etc..

Now I want to select from data from table where group like item1, item2, item3 etc..

My SQL Query is as follows

```
UniTable1.SQL.Text := Select * from emp where group like (:grp);
UniTable1.Params.ParamByName('grp').Value := glist;
```

But above SQL is returning error as 'like item1, item2, item3' is not a proper format is there any alterante way to create SQL query so that it will return data from selected group at CheckListEdit ?

Comment: This is sadly one of the cases where you have to build your query without using parameters...

Comment: The Like operator doesn't support multiple arguments. I don't suppose the In operator would suit your needs?

Comment: Here is [one way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401777/800214) to deal with this problem:

Comment: I do not know the DB components that you are using but check if they have a Macro `property`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of building a string as 'item1, item2, item3', you need to build it as '(item1, item2, item3)'. Then your query will become

```
Select * from emp where group in (item1, item2, item3)
```

As whosrdaddy pointed out, you will have to build the query as a concatenated string; it's not possible to pass the list of values as a parameter.

Comment: When I wrote  UniTable1.SQL.Text := 'Select * from emp where pgroup in (officer, manager, clerk)'  ... it is giving error like 'No Such Column: officer'.

Comment: If I wrote something like this it works  UniTable1.SQL.Text := 'Select * from emp where pgroup in (''officer'','' manager'', clerk'')'

Comment: It depends on your database. I normally only use integers (ie keys) in such a query ('where pgroup in (1,2,3)'). I would think that alphanumeric values would have to be passed in single quotes, not doubles, which would mean that in your program you would have to write two single quotes before and after each value. It's best to check the query with some command line tool first.

Comment: @Noám Newman, it worked finally with string value with slight change in above query without using parameters      UniTable1.SQL.Text := 'Select * from emp where pgroup in ('+ glist +')'

Answer (score 2):

Using parameter in the IN operator is not correct.You should either use an IN parameter list (:p1, :p2, ..., :pN) or use macros:

```
UniQuery.SQL.Text := 'Select * from emp where group in (&grp)';
UniQuery.MacroByName('grp').AsString := glist;
UniQuery.MacroByName('grp').Active := true;
```