# Need assistance with SQL in Excel, specifically the "?" Parameter

Tags: sql, excel, vba, parameters

I've set up this SQL query in excel:

```
SELECT * FROM acct.view_op_seremain

WHERE SEC_ID = (?)
```

I've directed the "?" parameter to cell A1 in Excel. Now, I want this A1 parameter cell to contain multiple values but I am unsure if it requires special formatting? So far I have tried to do the following in Cell A1:

```
Justin, John, James

('Justin','John','James')

'Justin','John','James'
```

None of those formats are giving me results. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. It's just that `=` compares only a single value, and you're trying to give it multiple ones. Try an `IN` statement:

```
WHERE SEC_ID IN (?)
```

And then this input string should work:

```
'Justin','John','James'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass multiple parameters in that way.

Depending on what database you're using, you may be able to pass a single string parameter to the databaase engine, and have the database engine split the string for you.

For example, [this answer has a solution for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401641/passing-a-sql-parameter-to-an-in-clause-using-typed-datasets-in-net/5401777#5401777).