# How to input an array to IN clause in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

```
string[] questions= new[] { "2","5","1","11","3","1"};

    select description,count(description) 
      from descriptions 
inner join questions 
        on descriptions.qid=questions.id 
     where descriptions.question=N'hardtest' 
       and qid in (?) 
  group by description
```

I want to use an array in this code as an input to `IN` clause. How can I do that?

```
qid in ('" + list + "')
```

Comment: What is your qid type?

Comment: thank you bro , this is my first question

Comment: qid is string type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a SQL parameter to an IN() clause using typed datasets in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401641/passing-a-sql-parameter-to-an-in-clause-using-typed-datasets-in-net)

Comment: but qid can be an int type

Comment: can i use list instead of array? i tried but not works
List<string> list = new List<string>(questions);

Comment: You need to pass your items as a DataTable and use a table valued parameter.

Comment: Better is to use the table variable  if you are using MS SQL otherwise try to convert the array value to compatible with In clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] questions = new[] { "2", "5", "1", "11", "3", "1" };

string qids = string.Empty;
questions.All((x) => { qids += "','" + x; return true; });
qids = qids.Substring(2);

string sql = @"
select description, count(description)
  from descriptions
inner join questions
    on descriptions.qid = questions.id
where descriptions.question = N'hardtest'
   and qid in ("+qids+@"')
group by description";
```

Comment: i'll wait until another optimized code ,if...

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack.

Comment: since the qid is int,the simpliest way is :questions.All((x) => { qids += Int32.TryParse(x,out id)?"','" + x:""; return true; });