# Insert a string as a parameter to a where IN clause in NET CORE

Tags: sql, asp.net-core

How can you insert a `WHERE IN` clause using parameter in net core? They are a list of strings. I have tried everything but doesn't seem to work. Tried `String.Join("','",myList)` and it looked ok but it doesn't return from the database. Tried the same query on sql server and returns the data as expected.

Comment: That's not really possible as the commas in the list are not treated as delimiters but just a value. However, using dynamic SQL you can work around it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401641/passing-a-sql-parameter-to-an-in-clause-using-typed-datasets-in-net. Be super careful and properly escape the strings; otherwise you create an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I have come up with a solution which is not the best but works perfectly. I return the full list from the database then using linq I query the object using .WHERE(x=>object.Contains(x.item)). This filters out the needed data and returns back what i need.