# Java / PostgreSQL - Data Optimization for Performance

Tags: java, postgresql, optimization, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

it's been a while. I'm currently struggling on optimizing the performance of my application. Here's a snippet similar to what I currently have.

A Stored procedure with this query:

```
SELECT field_a, field_b, field_c
FROM table_a
WHERE field_a = param_a
AND field_b = param_b;
```

In Java, I have this `ArrayList` of `SampleParameterClass` with attributes of `paramA` and `paramB` declared as `String`.

```
ArrayList<SampleParameterClass> sampleParams = new ArrayList<SampleParameterClass>();

sampleParams.add(new SampleParameterClass(stringValueForParamA, stringValueForParamB);
```

Let's assume that `sampleParams` is populated by hundreds of elements.

```
try
    {
        conn = ConnectionPool.getConnection();

        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        CallableStatement myProcedure = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call my_proc_name(?, ?) }");

        for(int paramCounter = 0; paramCounter < sampleParams.size(); paramCounter ++){

            myProcedure.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
            myProcedure.setObject(2, sampleParams.get(paramCounter).getParamA);
            myProcedure.setObject(3, sampleParams.get(paramCounter).getParamB);
            myProcedure.execute();

            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) myProcedure.getObject(1);

            while (rs.next()) {

                String resultA = rs.getString("param_a");
                String resultB = rs.getString("param_b");
                String resultC = rs.getString("param_c");

                myArrayListOfResult.add(new Result(resultA, resultB, resultC);

            }
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        myProcedure.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Basically, what the code above does is to loop throughout all the parameters in the `ArrayList` and call the stored procedure for every parameter. If I have a thousands of data to be processed, it would be slow as a snail isn't it?

My question would be:
1) Is it possible to call the procedure just once even though I have thousands of parameters in queue? Something similar to passing the whole `ArrayList` of parameters.
2) If above question cannot be answered, are there any method to minimize the process?

Note:
-Same question for a procedure with an `INSERT` statement.
-I haven't found a similar question to this, if I missed something. Please do post a URL to that question and I'll mark it as an answer to this question.
-I haven't found a reading material something like passing a list in a procedure.
Thanks, any answer is much appreciated.

Comment: In what you've written, i don't see any reason for this to be a stored procedure. You could use a normal `PreparedStatement`, and probably make your life a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks Tom. The stored proc written above is for the sake of my question. Currently, the procedure actually includes at least 8 tables. On the other hand, about your suggestion, wouldn't that be the same as if it were a procedure? The query will also be called based on the number of elements in my sampleParams?

Comment: You're right that using a `PreparedStatement` doesn't fix that problem. But user2310289's answer gives a solution which works for both `CallableStatement` and `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Thank you Tom! I'm currently working on it. As soon as I'm done, I'll mark his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass the parameters as a delimtered string and then use string_to_array(text, text [, text]) on the postgresql side to convert the string into an array.

See 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

and

[Postgres integer arrays as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570393/postgres-integer-arrays-as-parameters)

Comment: You don't even need to encode the array as a string - the PostgreSQL JDBC driver will accept them as instances of [`java.sql.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html). You can create those with [`Connection#createArrayOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29) and use them with [`PreparedStatement#setArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29).

Comment: There's a section on [Using Array Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) in the JDBC tutorial.

Comment: Marked as answered. Thank you user2310289. I would like to thank you by your name.