# How call function with array parameter postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function

i have a records in my table

```
testing=# select * from employee;
 employee_id | first_name | last_name | manager_id
-------------+------------+-----------+------------
           1 | Sandeep    | Jain      |
           2 | Abhishek   | Kelenia   |          1
           3 | Harsh      | Aggarwal  |          1
           4 | Raju       | Kumar     |          2
           5 | Nikhil     | Aggarwal  |          2
           6 | Anshul     | Aggarwal  |          2
           7 | Virat      | Kohli     |          3
           8 | Rohit      | Sharma    |          3
(8 rows)
```

i have written a function to delete record from table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(first_name varchar(255))
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE emp_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
 SELECT id into emp_id from links e where name = first_name;
 
 DELETE FROM links WHERE id = emp_id;

 return emp_id;

END

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but now i want to delete multiple records by passing array parameters.

Comment: Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/571205/7454336

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.