# Pass an array to a query in Postgres to check if a value is contained in the array

Tags: postgresql

I have an array with some ids on the front-end and I'm writing a query to check if I can find any user with a user_id inside the array, the table is very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE user_accounts (
  user_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  name TEXT,
  connector_type connector_type_enum NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
);
```

The array on the front-end is something like `["328hdgyas78g2", "3adhdayas7453"]`

and here's the query:

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    user_accounts
    WHERE   user_id IN $1
```

of course there's a syntax error, I have tried the following:

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    user_accounts
    WHERE   user_id = ANY(ARRAY["328hdgyas78g2", "3adhdayas7453"])
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "328hdgyas78g2" does not exist
```

How can I fix the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `"` is used to reference a column or table name. To reference a string you use the single `'`

You have a couple of options there

```
WHERE   user_id = ANY(ARRAY['328hdgyas78g2', '3adhdayas7453'])
```

or

```
WHERE   user_id = ANY('{328hdgyas78g2,3adhdayas7453}')
```

Also, good reference is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570393/postgres-integer-arrays-as-parameters)